# Cómo incluir dos condiciones en WHERE en la actualización de base de datos MYSQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un proyecto en PHP conectado a MYSQL con la siguiente información:

ID, NOMBRE, FECHA_INICIO, FECHA_FIN, ESTADO

El siguiente código actualiza el campo ESTADO según la fecha actual del sistema y la información del campo FECHA_INICIO y FECHA_FIN

```
    $sql2="UPDATE curso SET ESTADO='Por Registrar' WHERE FECHA_INICIO > CURDATE()";
    $statement2 = $con->prepare($sql2);
    $statement2->execute();

    $sql="UPDATE curso SET ESTADO='Registrado' WHERE FECHA_FIN < CURDATE()";
    $statement = $con->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que en el campo ESTADO se incluya el texto 'En Registro' cuando la fecha actual del sistema es mayor o igual a la FECHA_INICIO y menor o igual a la FECHA_FIN en otras palabras que esté ENTRE esas dos fechas.

Aprovechando, los códigos funcionan correctamente, pero hay que presionar F5 dos veces para que la página muestre los cambios, qué código se puede adicionar para actualizar la información cargando la página solo una vez ?

MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar una sentencia [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) para hacer todo en una consulta.

Te recomiendo que renombres tu tabla a "cursos" (en plural), por convención las tablas que no son pivots van en plural. Tu tabla contiene *cursos* no un *curso*.

```
UPDATE cursos SET estado = CASE
  WHEN CURDATE() > fecha_fin THEN 'Registrado'
  WHEN CURDATE() >= fecha_inicio THEN 'En registro'
  ELSE 'Por registrar'
END;
```

En una sentencia `CASE` se devuelve el valor de la primera condición que se evalúa como verdadera.

- Se empieza el chequeo para saber si el curso finalizó (no lo tenías en tu pregunta, pero sirve a modo de ejemplo): `CURDATE() > fecha_fin`.
- Si no finalizó, entonces se chequea si inició: `CURDATE() >= fecha_inicio`. Si eso es verdadero, es implícito que además `CURDATE() <= fecha_fin`, ya que mayor no puede ser porque lo chequeamos arriba.
- Por último, si no finalizó, ni inició, entonces es a futuro: `ELSE`.

Con esa sola consulta actualizás todos los estados, no hace falta hacer más de una.

Te dejo un ejemplo acá: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ada9368a875b54e95168b21f0df8af1e)

En cuanto a por qué tenés que actualizar 2 veces la página para que se vean reflejados los cambios, no se. Tendrías que publicar el código completo que estás utilizando. No estarás trayendo primero la información de la base de datos y actualizando después?